# Extracting data from a text file and output xml file

Tags: xml, linux

cat Test1.txt

```
id=1
bytes=29086
time=583ms
```

cat Test2.txt

```
id =2
bytes=29096
time=83ms

...
```

cat Testn.txt

```
id =n
bytes=29096
time=83ms
```

expect output result.xml

```
<result>
<test><id>1</id><time>583ms</time></test>
<test><id>2</id><time>83ms</time></test>
...
<test><id>n</id><time>83ms</time></test>
</result>
```

for poor in linux shell,I hava trid to solve it ,but still not runing.

Comment: all files in the folder /var/log/tmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a shell script that does what you want

```
echo "<result>"
for f in Test*.txt
  do
    source $f
    echo "<test><id>"$id"</id><time>"$time"</time></test>"
  done
echo "</result>"
```

Save the output to `result.xml`